# How can i peek next token in flex without removing it from buffer

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer, lex, ampl

I'm trying to build lexer for some subset of AMPL language.
I need to now what type of symbolic name lexer is dealing right now.
Every symbolic name is var or param or set. Fortunately all of them have to be declared before they are used. So i thought i can use lookahead operator in flex simply changing code in lexer from

```
SYMBOLIC_NAME [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
%%
param             { return PARAM; }
var               { return VAR; }
set               { return SET; }
{SYMBOLIC_NAME}   { yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);
                    return SYMBOLIC_NAME;  
                  }
%%
```

to some thing like this

```
SYMBOLIC_NAME [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
%{
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 std::vector<std::string> paramNames;
 std::vector<std::string> setNames;
 std::vector<std::string> varNames;

%}
%%
param/(.|\n)+{SYMBOLIC_NAME}             { paramNames.push_back(&yytext[5]);
                                           return PARAM; }
var/(.|\n)+{SYMBOLIC_NAME}               { varNames.push_back(&yytext[3]);
                                           return VAR; }
set/(.|\n)+{SYMBOLIC_NAME}               { setNames.push_back(&yytext[3]);
                                           return SET; }
{SYMBOLIC_NAME}   { if ( std::find(setNames.begin(), setNames.end(), yytext) != setNames.end() ) {
                    yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);
                    return SET_NAME;
                    }

                   if ( std::find(paramNames.begin(), paramNames.end(), yytext) != paramNames.end() ){
                    yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);
                    return PARAM_NAME;  
                  }
                  if ( std::find(varNames.begin(), varNames.end(), yytext) != varNames.end() ){
                    yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);
                    return VAR_NAME;  
                  }
               }
%%
```

I know it's not going to work because *yytext* does not contain second part of first three regexps.
And question appears how can i peek what is under **(.|\n)+{SYMBOLIC_NAME}** .

PS

I know the code is not optimal but it is not an issue here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to check a symbol table for what kind of name you are seeing.

If that is the case, you should do this by communicating through the symbol table. That is:

1. Create a simple "symbol" rule. Your original rule is fine:

   ```
   {SYMBOLIC_NAME}   { yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);
                   return SYMBOLIC_NAME;  
                 }
   ```
2. Handle the declaration syntax at the parser level:

   ```
   var_decl : VAR SYMBOLIC_NAME
        { add name to symbol table }
   ```
3. Now go back and extend your SYMBOLIC_NAME rule to check for defined symbols:

   ```
   {SYMBOLIC_NAME} {
                yylval.string = (char*) strdup(yytext);

                if ( std::find(setNames.begin(), setNames.end(), yytext) != setNames.end() ) {
                    return SET_NAME;
                }
                else if (... varNames ...) {
                    return VAR_NAME;
                else if (... paramNames ...) {
                    return PARAM_NAME;
                }
                else {
                    return SYMBOLIC_NAME;
                }
            }
   ```

Now you have one Flex target returning four possible tokens, depending on defined-ness. But Flex doesn't have to worry about remembering what symbol definition is active - you can let the parser handle that.

On the parser side, you write different rules:

```
var_decl: VAR SYMBOLIC_NAME
set_decl: SET SYMBOLIC_NAME

expr: atom '+' atom
atom: VAR_NAME | SET_NAME | PARAM_NAME
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank You for solution

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively do the "peeking" using start conditions, but if what you're actually trying to do is maintain a symbol table, and have the lexer automatically return the correct semantic category for each symbol, there is a better solution (see below).

First of all, instead of using three `std::vector` lists, and searching each one linearly until you find the symbol, you would really be better off using a single `std::unordered_map` to associate each name with a semantic type. (I know you said not to think about the inefficiency of the code, but this change makes things quite a bit simpler.)

If you want the *lexer* to be responsible for maintaining the symbol table, that can easily be done although it's a bit forced since the parser will also need to store semantic information associated with each symbol. All the same, it's not too painful. Below I use a single start condition to collect the defined name after a definition keyword (which is basically what your lookahead does, but this way the lexer isolates the actual name being defined instead of a string starting with a variable amount of whitespace).

Here I take advantage of the fact that the hash table includes a `std::string` representing the name of the symbol, by setting `yylval.string` to the internal C string from the hash table entry. That's perfectly safe as long as you don't modify the contents of `yylval.string`, since symbols are never deleted from the symbol table and a hash table never moves its elements. In practice, it might well be better to make the `yylval` union member:

```
%union {
   std::string* string;
   // ...
}
```

but that's a minor detail. Here's the scanner:

```
%{
   #include <unordered_map>
   namespace {
     enum class Kind { UNDEFINED, PARAM, SET, VAR };
     std::unordered_map<std::string, Kind> symbols;
   }
%}
%x SC_DEFINE

id [[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*

%%
  /* Up to the first unindented line is inserted at the beginning of yylex */
  Kind to_define;

<*>[[:space:]] /* Ignore in all start conditions */
param          { kind_to_define = Kind::PARAM; BEGIN(SC_DEFINE); }
set            { kind_to_define = Kind::SET; BEGIN(SC_DEFINE); }
var            { kind_to_define = Kind::VAR; BEGIN(SC_DEFINE); }
{id}           { auto it = symbols.emplace(yytext, Kind::UNKNOWN).first;
                 yylval.string = it->first.c_str();
                 switch (it->second) {
                     case Kind::PARAM: return PARAM_NAME;
                     case Kind::SET:   return SET_NAME;
                     case Kind::VAR:   return VAR_NAME;
                     default:          return UNDEFINED_NAME;
                 }
               }
<SC_DEFINE>{id} { auto itbool = symbols.emplace(yytext, to_define);
                  if (!itbool.second) {
                    if (itbool.first->second != Kind::UNKNOWN) {
                      /* Redefinition: handle the error somehow */
                    } else {
                      /* Used previously, error presumably already issued */
                      itbool.first->second = to_define;
                    }
                  }
                  BEGIN(INITIAL);
                  yylval.string = itbool.first->first.c_str();
                  switch (to_define) {
                    case Kind::PARAM: return DEFINE_PARAM;
                    case Kind::SET: return DEFINE_SET;
                    case Kind::VAR: return DEFINE_VAR;
                    default: /* Logic error */
                  }
                }
```

**Note:** The above returns a `DEFINE_PARAM` (for example) token which *already indicates the name of the symbol* (in `yylval.string`), so your grammar rule would have to be, for example, `param_definition: DEFINE_PARAM ...` instead of `param_definition: PARAM SYMBOL ...`.

One thing I didn't do above is fill in the other entries in the `SC_DEFINE` start condition: any other token is (presumably) a syntax error, including any keyword tokens which you happen to need (such as `var`, `set` and `param`, for example).

I think that will work, although I haven't actually tried to compile it. But it's more than a little clunky.

IMHO, a much better approach is to share the symbol table between the parser and the lexer. (The bison manual explains how to provide extra arguments to `yylex`, and the flex manual explains how to receive them.) The basic symbol table would look as it does above, except that it would belong the the parser, or more accurately the program which calls the parser. However, it would probably have more semantic information than just the symbol kind. The mapped value might be a discriminated union, a `boost::variant` or whatever else proved to be convenient.

In that case, the scanner would be much as outline above, but without the start condition. When it sees an undefined symbol (as it should when scanning the symbol following a definition keyword), it will return an `UNDEFINED_NAME` token, so your parser's rules would look something like:

```
param_definition: PARAM UNDEFINED_NAME ...
```

and in the semantic action for the definition, the parser will fill in the symbol's kind along with any other useful information. In this case, it would probably be convenient for `yylval.symbol` to be a pointer to the value in the symbol table (*not* the iterator, which could be invalidated, but rather `&*iterator` which is stable) so that the lookup doesn't need to be repeated.

In this scenario, using an undefined symbol and attempting to define an already defined symbol will both naturally be syntax errors, since the parser will have no rules which handle those cases. To provide meaningful error messages, you might want to add such rules as error cases.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't care in the grammar. Your grammar should just handle `IDENTIFIER` and then lookup the symbol table itself for the semantic actions.

All this mucking around in the lexer is certainly the wrong way to do it.